# Install LimeSurvery 4.2 with MSSQL option

Tags: php, sql-server, limesurvey

I am trying to install LimeSurvery 4.2 with MSSQL option, but unable to get the MSSQL option in database configuration screen only MySQL option in dropdown.
Already Install Microsoft library for PHP SQLServer, register the dlls in php.ini

- extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
- extension=php_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
- extension=php_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll

**Current PHP version is 7+**

Please help me out how to configure LimeSurvery with MSSQL server.

Answer (score 0):

for sqlsrv : you need complete PHP number version.

If you have 7.2 : you need `php_pdo_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll`  + `php_sqlsrv_72_ts.dll` only … see [microsoft manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/connect/php/microsoft-php-driver-for-sql-server) …

Check you error log of apache or IIS to know what happen

Maybe you need to add [ODBC Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/system-requirements-for-the-php-sql-driver) too